# SQL UPDATE statment

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have this query that returns me ids

```
select id, default_code from product_product ou
where (select count(*) from product_product inr
where inr.default_code = ou.default_code) > 1 and ou.active = false
```

but i'm getting syntax error with this statement

```
update product_product ou
where (select count(*) from product_product inr
where inr.default_code = ou.default_code) > 1 and ou.active = false set uo.default_code = uo.default_code || 'A';

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 2:     where (select count(*) from product_product inr
```

how do i update correctly ids that i retrieve from first statement

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct:

```
update
    product_product ou
set
    default_code = ou.default_code || 'A'
from
    (
        select default_code
        from product_product
        group by default_code
        having count(*) > 1
    ) inr
where
    not ou.active
    and ou.default_code = inr.default_code
```

Comment: ups.. ERROR:  column "ou" of relation "product_product" does not exist
LINE 4:     ou.default_code = ou.default_code || 'A'

Comment: @Chaban33 Corrected now. I forgot, you cannot put aliases on field to be set

Comment: This will not work: `set ou.default_code = someValueHere`. This will work: `set default_code = someValueHere`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below - using `JOIN`

```
update product_product ou
set default_code = concat(ou.default_code, 'A')
from 
 (
   select inr.default_code,count(*) from product_product inr
    group by inr.default_code having count(*)>1
 )A
where A.default_code = ou.default_code and ou.active = false
```

Comment: You are missing a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 8: on A.default_code = ou.default_code

Comment: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "uo"
LINE 2: set uo.default_code = concat(uo.default_code, 'A')

Comment: @Chaban33, you can checnk now

Comment: Still no `HAVING`? That code would be invalid if there is only 1 count. Might as well just write this: `update product_product set default_code = default_code || 'A'`

Comment: Anyway, I think the OP is just looking for the right syntax for UPDATE from a result. I think he put `HAVING` in his final code

Comment: Actually as i executed it it updated 174 records, but my queary returns only 71, so it's not working properly, sorry

Comment: Because you forgot `HAVING`, that's all :)

Comment: yeh i noticed that you insist on it :D need to google a bit about having , because don't know where to use it

Comment: I provided an answer where to put it :)

Comment: @Chaban33, I've added the having in the query - now i think it will work

Comment: Your description is wrong, you're not using `JOIN` :P If I remember correctly, Postgres does not allow `JOIN` in its UPDATE statement, only when it is in subquery. SQL Server does allow JOIN to its UPDATE table

Comment: @MichaelBuen - chk here http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-update-join/

Comment: @fa06 You're correct, I revisited my old blog. UPDATE can be joined on Postgres. But it's convoluted when compared to SQL Server. SQL Server UPDATE+JOIN syntax is cleaner, it does not need a WHERE clause. UPDATE+JOIN would suffice in SQL Server. Postgres's UPDATE+JOIN need a WHERE clause: http://mssql-to-postgresql.blogspot.com/2007/12/updates-in-postgresql-ms-sql-mysql.html.

Comment: @MichaelBuen, I've described becuase it's kind of updating using multiple tables - product to product the syntax may vary , but concept is same